# Customize Apache index pages with messages

Tags: apache, mod-autoindex

I would like to customize a specific directory shared with Apache with messages, as seen in this picture from [this link](http://www-verimag.imag.fr/DIST-TOOLS/SYNCHRONE/lustre-v6/) with the message down below. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Check out [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_autoindex.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize **mod_autoindex** settings.

Looks like **ReadmeName** directive is what you need.

Read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#readmename) documentation.